# creating dynamic html c#

Tags: c#, html, dynamic

i wanted to create a web server while on the process.....

i am not being able to create a dynamic html which could take link from my c# console application...

for example i have a code which shows files from the system.. for example "c:\tike\a.jpeg" now i wanted to make that particular link a a href link in my html page...

any help would be appreciated.....
thank you..

(to sum up ... i want to create dynamic html page which takes value from c# console application.)

Comment: To clarify: From your previous questions it seems you're building a web-server. Now you want to generate an "index" page for a directory, i.e. an HTML page that automatically lists all files in that directory with HTML links to the files. Is this correct?

Comment: @dtb yes.. you are rite.

Comment: @james Black.. i am blank in this context so i wanted to get some idea if possible few hint on code would be great.... thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring virtual paths etc. for now, here is a *simple* example to get you started:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("<html>");
sb.AppendLine("<head>");
sb.AppendLine("<title>Index of c:\\dir</title>");
sb.AppendLine("</head>");
sb.AppendLine("<body>");
sb.AppendLine("<ul>");

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\dir");
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i) {
    string name = Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i]);

    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<li><a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a></li>",
        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name)),
        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(name)));
}

sb.AppendLine("</ul>");
sb.AppendLine("</body>");
sb.AppendLine("</html>");
string result = sb.ToString();
```

`result` contains a string that you can send as body of an HTTP response to the web-browser.

*(Note: I typed the code right into the answer box, no idea if it compiles as-is.)*

Comment: No overload for method 'Appendline' takes '3' arguments

Comment: Forgot `string.Format`. Fixed.